# Add custom css to Jekyll

Tags: css, jekyll

Im new to Jekyll and I am making a site with custom html and css in order.  Jekyll downloads the minima theme by default, so I overrode the homepage with the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>testsite</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    all my html

    <script>
           $.ajax(an ajax call);        
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am looking to add a custom stylesheet, yet I am having trouble correctly linking to within the theme.  I have checked online but many forums seem out incorrect on the folder structure.

Here is the current structure.

```
--layouts
  -home.html
--posts
--site
  --assets
    -main.css
    -main.css.map
  --jekyll
    --update
  --privacy
  -index.html
--jekyll-cache
-config.yml
-Gemfile
-Gemfile.lock
-index.markdown
```

My question is, is there a simple way to add a stylesheet that will work on all pages when live?  I can link a stylesheet the normal way id do it, however that doesn't work when uploaded to github.  Would it be better to start from a build without a theme?  If so how do I setup the gemfile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great simple approach. I love it. Here is how to proceed:

1. Remove Minima from your config file/project
2. Create a directory _includes
3. Move the head to header.html in _includes
4. Call the header in the home.html (and any other layout) file by using {% include header.html %}
5. Link the new CSS in the header.html file

Jekyll without themes (and plugins) is so much better. Looking for more? https://www.jekyllcodex.org