# My site is based on jekyll, how can I use CSS flexbox to stylize a section of it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, jekyll

I am a beginner at web development, and I just want to make a small website based on jekyll. So I have created 4 posts, and they show up nicely on the website. The thing is that they actually show up on the bottom of the page, under stuff I put in index.md (which takes up like the whole page); I want to find a way to move the whole post section to the right so it's parallel to the content in my index.md. I tried CSS flexbox, but I can't find where to add the codes because the posts are found in a separate folder and don't show up in my index.md. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63555632/add-custom-css-to-jekyll

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a different Jekyll template from the one you are using now instead of adapting your current one. The template my university provide for Jekyll in our institutional GITLAB, for instance, has posts above content in the index.md file. And it can be tricky to adjust themes.

However, there are Jekyll templates with a two-column layout with a side-bar.

You might want to check out the ["Minimal Mistakes" theme](https://jekyllthemes.io/theme/minimal-mistakes) or the ["Hyde" theme](https://jekyllthemes.dev/a-brazen-two-column-theme-for-jekyll/).